# toggle elements by ids with consecutive numbered IDs

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am completely lost here.
I am trying to have a visibility toggle for called multiple elements with consecutively numbered IDs. The Class is already used for another function. I want the script to run a loop to get all elements that have the set ID and consecutive number to toggle visibility.
this is the code I have.

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="tag" id="angels" onclick="toggle_visibility('angelT');" />
<label for="angels"><span>Hide Angels</span>

</label>
</div>
<div id="angelT1" style="display:block">angel1</div>
<div id="angelT2" style="display:block">angel2</div>
<div id="angelT3" style="display:block">angel3</div>
<div id="angelT4" style="display:block">angel4</div>
<div id="angelT5" style="display:block">angel5</div>
<div id="angelT6" style="display:block">angel6</div>
```

And this is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function toggle_visibility(prefix) {
   var i = 0;
   var e = null;

   do {
     ++i;
     var id = prefix + i;

     e = document.getElementById(id);

     if (e) 
       if (e.style.display == 'block') 
         e.style.display = 'none';
       else 
         e.style.display = 'block';
   } while (e);
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/lhHby

Comment: This is the one. Thank you so much. Now to code 1300 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` selector is very specific, and none of the ids on your elements will match. You may be better off using a common `class` to accomplish this:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="tag" id="angels" onclick="toggle_visibility('angelT');" />
<label for="angels"><span>Hide Angels</span>

</label>
</div>
<div id="angelT1" class="angelT" style="display:block">angel1</div>
<div id="angelT2" class="angelT" style="display:block">angel2</div>
<div id="angelT3" class="angelT" style="display:block">angel3</div>
<div id="angelT4" class="angelT" style="display:block">angel4</div>
<div id="angelT5" class="angelT" style="display:block">angel5</div>
<div id="angelT6" class="angelT" style="display:block">angel6</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(className) {
        var e = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            if (e[i].style.display == 'block') e[i].style.display = 'none';
            else e[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using jquery now solve this way

```
$( "div[id^='"+id+"']" ).toogle();
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/